# How do i switch to a local version of a node_modules file that I've saved to desktop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, charles-proxy

I'm trying to make some changes to the react-rte text editor but can't test it...

I've noticed literally nothing is coming through to the client after putting in console.logs, alerts, new code etc.

How do i proxy (?) or bounce the requests to 1 or 2 specific files in node_modules, so the webapp/node server pull in my local file saved on my desktop eg `desktop/my-edited-file.js`.

**Official File:**

```
my-project:
    --node_modules/react-rte/lib/lib/EditorToolbar.js
      ▲ this file ▲
    --pkg json
    --ReadMe.md
    --yarn.lock
    --src/
    ----app.js
    ----header.js etc
```

**Edited File:**

`/Users/DesLynham/desktop/myBalls.js`

please help

Comment: Have you tried chanding the import to `/Users/DesLynham/desktop/myBalls.js`? (I'm not really thinking it'll work but it's a start to figure it out)

Answer (score 0):

You can map any HTTP request to a local file on your computer using [CharlesProxy's Map Local feature](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-local/).